# No main manifest attribute when trying to run Spring boot application jar

Tags: java, spring-boot, command-line, jar

I am trying to run my Spring Boot application through the command line but I am getting the error `no main manifest attribute`.

I checked my project folder and there is indeed a MANIFEST.MF file that contains

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: com.migrations.demo.MigrationsApplication
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWfYs.png

How can I fix this?

### pom File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.migrations</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Migrations</name>
    <description>Demonstration of some migrations</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>15</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

### Steps to build jar

[image]

To run the jar I am using java -jar path

Comment: You shouldn't need to configure the manifest when you're using Spring Boot as it should set that up for you automatically as part of building your application's fat jar. I can see from your screenshot that you're using Maven. Can you share your pom.xml and the commands that you're using to build and run the jar file please?

Comment: The manifest was generated automatically. I will update my question with the details you asked for